# Usage of Dependency Injection in .NET Core while respecting Inversion of Control

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

My aim is to write a library with .NET Core that consumes a REST API. For that I have several classes which manage calls to different endpoints as well as queuing. Eventually, I will have one class that depends on `HttpClient` and after reading about it, it seems that a desirable approach of handling its lifetime is to use dependency injection, which leads me to my problem, which is more of general nature (so if your opinion on HttpClient differs, that is not part of the question).

Let us assume the call is made with the help of the following class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProducerConsumer
{
    internal class EndpointAHandler
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public EndpointAHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        }

        public async Task<JsonDocument> Fetch(Command command)
        {
            return await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync((string)command.Parameters["url"]));
        }
    }
}
```

So what I would like to do is to dependency inject the `HttpClient` service which I could do by calling `AddHttpClient()` to my services or by injecting `IHttpClientFactory` (based on [.Net Core Tutorials](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/03/httpclient-factories-in-net-core-2-1/)).

The problem that I now have is that I have no idea how to actually call the `Fetch()` method, as I cannot manually create an instance of it using new. Also, using the service locator pattern is not really an option, as it's considered an anti-pattern. So it seems that I fundamentally understand something wrong. It would be nice to use DI as I could also use that for e.g. mocking services for testing or for changing some behavior during development.

Other posts on Stack Overflow hint towards me not completely understanding the inversion of control principle. If I compare e.g. with ASP.NET controllers, where dependency injection is also used, they somehow "magically" receive the incoming requests without actually being directly invoked anywhere in the code. I assume this is the direction I have to go, but I don't see how I can do this. If anyone could shed some light on the principles that would be of help. Also, if there is an easy way for putting the answer into could, that would help as well.

Comment: In order to take advantage of DI, you should be registering and injecting `EndpointAHandler` (or an associated interface). For more help, you'll probably need to share more details of how this class and the library in general is to be used

Comment: You only have two options: "dependency injection all the way down" which is what other people told you or use service locator pattern.

Comment: @devNull I can do that, but then I have another injection which I actually do not need. The calling class can then also not by created by its constructor any more (as I have a DI in there) which means that I have to inject this one as well. And this chain escalates until I have to inject multiple (MANY) services in an upper class that the class itself actually does not really depend on (lets say my database service is only required by one underlying class). Than all classes above need to pass it on? That adds more dependencies than originally? I guess I am wrong... :o

Comment: @LostInComputer At the moment it looks like this, but then DI does not really make life easier, it just adds a lot of trouble (at least from my perspective). Is this really the way to go? For me it seems that I somehow have to decouple this "all the way down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to continue that pattern of dependency injection, the important question is less "How do I call the Fetch method?" but rather "Where do I need to call the Fetch method from?"

What you're creating above is roughly a typed HttpClient, which you probably came across in looking through [the HttpClientFactory documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) that's available from Microsoft; it requires an HttpClient instance and then provides a more tightly controlled set of actions around that instance.

When you create something like a class library, it then becomes the responsibility of the consuming application to register that client into its own service container so that it is available for any injected dependencies there, either within your code or to be exposed to the client to use directly. In order to make that possible, a common practice would be to write some sort of builder or static extension method for the service collection to help make it easier to handle that registration:

```
public static class MyLibraryServiceExtensions 
{

    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.AddHttpClient<IMyTypedClient, MyTypedClient>();
        services.AddTransient<ISomeOtherDependency, SomeOtherDependency>();
        // whatever else you need to register

        return services;
    }
}
```

With this in place, the consumer could do `services.AddMyLibrary()` during their Startup or composition root, and any place your components are then injected would be able to take advantage of them.

You can see Microsoft doing that itself for its own `services.AddHttpClient()` in GitHub here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your gave me some useful insights (exposing the service registration) which I didn't really consider. Still, it does not completely solve the original problem.

Comment: I think there is still some ambiguity as to where your handler needs to be called from that is making it difficult to answer this effectively. Looking at some of your other comments and concerns about explosions of DI with 20+ injections lends itself to the idea that there's some design in mind with code smells around violating SRP, but its hard to suss out. Is this handler in a controller? Sitting on the other side of a message bus like MediatR?

Comment: There is no application yet, I am about to design it. My thought was: Lets say I have one class for each API endpoint (20) and each needs an ```HttpClient``` and I have one class that takes a request and looks which endpoint and thus which class handles the current request. If I need to also inject the API endpoint classes (as I cannot say new ```Service().Fetch(request)``` into this handler, I need to inject all 20 classes. As the handler has DI for its constructor, also the class using the handler needs to inject all classes. And that continues. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: It seems like there might be a fundamental misunderstanding of DI here? When things are registered into the container and become part the dependency graph, you no longer have to pass all of the layered dependencies around; if `MyHandlerOne` depends on `MyClientOne` and `MyClientOne` depends on `MySettingsOne` and they're all registered, each service only needs to have passed in the constructor the things it directly references and that entire chain of downstream dependencies for newing up the rest is handled for you, you don't have to explicitly pass in, say, `MySettingsOne` to `MyHandlerOne`.

Comment: Hm I see, I think your "Where do I need to call the Fetch method from?" is the approach that I have to follow. So in my example, the "main" handler will have ```EndpointAHandler``` as an injected dependency and does not care about the ```WebClient```. One last stylistic question then: For me it seems creating a new service for each endpoint does not make that much sense, as I would have to inject all of them which are quite many if there are many APIs. Is there a better approach than just combining all of them into one big class/service? Maybe one service with consists of multiple classes?

Comment: Yes, a class per endpoint is potentially overkill. Take a look at Microsoft's docs for creating a Web API in ASP NET Core; a single API controller can serve as many endpoints as logically makes sense based on their shared functionality or dependencies (And thus would all potentially share a single scoped typed HttpClient being injected): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

if you use DI, it is better to create all your classes with DI and use the ServiceProvider to get your instance of the Class.

in you example add your classes to the Service, in startup.cs if you use ASP or someware in the Programm startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddHttpClient()
                    .AddSingleton<EndpointAHandler>()
}
```

now you can load your EndpointAHandler by calling

```
var endpointAHandler = serviceProvider.GetService<EndpointAHandler>();
```

On ASP you can add the IServiceProvider as parameter in your Controller Constructor and use DI to get the serviceprovider.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me it looks like I will have an escalation of DI, where I have to "pass" all services through the whole application which seems weird. Assume that the class that uses ```EndpointAHandler``` will get it injected such that I don't have to use the service locator. Then, I also need inject this class to the next upper class and so on. If I have lets say 20 services in underlying classes, my upper most class needs 20 injections just to be able to pass the services on? That seems rather weird to me and adds more complexity than solving, or am I mistaken? I hope you understand my chain of thought

Comment: I don't mind using the service locator so much to "break" this chain of DI's, but this pattern is considered bad as the class constructor does not expose the classes dependencies :/

Comment: If your class needs 20 injections you can also inject just the serviceprovider and call the GetService<>() on that to get the instance. But of course, it's a design question.

Comment: That is actually a really good idea, thanks! Maybe I just have to play around a bit to get used to advantages and disadvantages.